# Replace string with values in array by array key

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to replace my strings with values in array by array key:

**Example 1:**

```
Array
(
    [cid] => 1-category-title
    [slug] => 100-article-title
)
```

My string: `products/{:cid}/{:slug}`

And I'm trying to replace it: `products/1-category-title/100-article-title`

**Example 2:**

```
Array
(
    [cid] => 1-category-title
    [slug] => 100-article-title
    [page_id] => 5
)
```

My string: `products/{:cid}/{:slug}`

And I'm trying to replace it: `products/1-category-title/100-article-title?page_id=5`

**Example 3:**

```
Array
(
    [cid] => 1-category-title
    [slug] => 100-article-title
    [page_id] => 5
    [format] => json 
)
```

My string: `products/{:cid}/{:slug}`

And I'm trying to replace it: `products/1-category-title/100-article-title?page_id=5&format=json`

Comment: Do you have a framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an example](https://3v4l.org/8imLT).

[Read this.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$array = array(
    "cid"=>"1-category-title",
    "slug"=> "100-article-title",
    "page_id" => 5
);

$string = "products/{:cid}/{:slug}";

$string = str_replace("{:cid}",$array['cid'], $string);
$string = str_replace("{:slug}",$array['slug'], $string);
if(!empty($array['page_id'])) $string .= "?page_id=".$array['page_id'];

echo $string;
```